# Firefox Mobile Addon SDK via Android usb connection error - package.json does not have a 'main' entry

Tags: android, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

My goal is to install a firefox addon on to an android device, but I ran into the following error...

```
"package.json does not have a 'main' entry."
```

Using

Windows 7 : Firefox 20.0 : Android SDK 4.2.2 w/ Google USB Driver : Just downloaded the Firefox SDK

Nexus 7 : Firefox Nightly with usb debug mode enabled

I installed python 2.6 and installed the latest Android sdk and verified that the versions matched my android device (Nexus 7) and the cfx test command comes back sucessful, but I am receiving the following error and have no idea where to start looking...

See the pastebin entry to view my command line entries and the error it is spitting at me...

http://pastebin.com/aXWxnKxw

I have been following the following tutorials:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/tutorials/installation.html
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/tutorials/mobile.html#cfx-options

Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found my answer... you have to run the command while in the addon's source folder.

See http://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2012/02/06/mobile-add-on-development-using-the-add-on-sdk/